# Write List of Tuples (int, float) to Stream Without Converting to String

Tags: python, list, io, byte

I have a list in Python that consists of tuples that have the following format: (int, float). I want to write this list to a io byte or io raw stream without having to convert the ints and/or floats to a string. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to write these objects to a stream, you have to convert them to bytes, one way or a another, i.e. to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) them. If you don't want to use string as the format, you have to choose some other format. What do you want? Why don't you want strings?

Comment: I don't want to convert them to strings because I am streaming data from a server to a client and I want to minimize the size of the payload. My integers are long and take up 32 bytes. My floats are 24 bytes. If I convert them to strings, the size of the payload will increase because each character in a string takes up 1 byte. But how do I serialize and unserialize these to/from bytes? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many formats which can be used to serialize Python objects into bytes. There are pros and cons for each of them.

If the data has only a list of tuples of integers and flaots, that make the job rather simple.

Let's assume, this is the data:

```
data = 100 * [(1, 1.111), (18, 1.234), (555555, 0.001), (-1, 1e70)]
```

Which of them falls into the category of "strings" is not clear to me. The most obvious "string" format would be `str(data)`. How big is it?

```
>>> len(str(data))
5500
```

This takes up 5500 bytes. The question asks for something more compressed. So, we're looking for something much shorter than 5500 bytes.

**JSON** is a very popular format (it is also a string). How big is it?

```
>>> len(json.dumps(data))
5500
```

This has the same size (5500 bytes), but at least it is well defined. Can it be smaller? How about a **BZipped JSON**?

```
>>> len(bz2.compress(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')))
131
```

That is much better!

This was probably very good because of a repeating pattern. Is there a format which does not use zipping? Maybe **pickle**?

```
>>> len(pickle.dumps(data))
862
```

Not as good as zip (of course!), but still good.

Could we make a **BZipped pickle**?

```
>>> len(bz2.compress(pickle.dumps(data)))
155
```

Better, but there is no reason for it to be better than BZipped JSON.

How about some other format? You could convert each tuple to the equivalent of this C **structure**, using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module:

```
struct {
    int i;
    double f;
};
```

However, then you'd have to know how big the int can be. Python int can be as big aas you want, but if you e.g. know that all numbers are between 0 and 255, you just need one byte. For the float, you need 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes), or you lose precision. So, this will go up to about 1000 bytes. Not very good.

There are also other built-in options documented in [Python's documentation on Persistence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html).

You can also invent your own format.

In the end, you have to decide what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump integers and floats into bytes directly really easily using the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = [(2, 1.0), (3, 2.0), (25, 55.5)]
>>> for tup in data:
    bytes_data = struct.pack("<ld", *tup)
    print(bytes_data)


b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@'
b'\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0K@'
```

As an aside the string I use as the first argument to the `pack` function is a format identifier that tells you what type and size of each number, in this case `l` is a long signed int, `d` is a float double.